# Order one variable by the proportion of another categorical variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where variable 1 contains categorical names of experiment's participants. There are duplicate values of variable 1 as there are multiple rows labeled for each participant. Each participant performs a similar task over and over which gives me a binary variable 2:

| Participant | Answer |
| --- | --- |
| P1 | Yes |
| P1 | Yes |
| P1 | Yes |
| P1 | No |
| P2 | Yes |
| P2 | No |
| P2 | No |
| P3 | No |

I am using R and I want to calculate the proportion of Yes answers for each participant and order the participant by that proportion. Eventually I want to plot these with ggplot such that the leftmost bar is the participant with the highest proportion and the rightmost bar with the lowest proportion.

I know how to make a table of the type described [here](https://stackoverflow.com) but I don't know how to then use it to create a bar plot so I am trying other methods.

Thanks for tips!

I tried:

```
data_df %>% group_by(Participant,Answer) %>% mutate(proportion = summarize(n = n()))
```

And got:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `proportion`.
ℹ `proportion = summarize(n = n())`.
x no applicable method for 'summarise' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: participant = "UIT001", answer = "Yes".
```

I don't get where the integer and numeric types are coming from because running `str(data_df)` return `chr` for both of these variables. I imagine it has to do with how
`group_by` works but I do not know what to do next.

I also tried the following solution found in Stack:

```
data_df <- data_df %>%
  group_by(participant) %>%
  mutate(Yes_ratio = n_distinct(participant[answer == "yes"])/n_distinct(participant))
```

But that returns 1 for each row.

Answer (score 1):

Since your responses are either "Yes" or "No", you could use `mean` in `dplyr::summarize` after grouping by participant ID.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Participant) %>%
  summarize(proportion = mean(Answer == "Yes"))

# or using .by in dplyr >= 1.1.0
df %>%
  summarize(proportion = mean(Answer == "Yes"), 
            .by = "Participant")
```

Output:

```
#  Participant proportion
#  <chr>            <dbl>
#1 P1               0.75 
#2 P2               0.333
#3 P3               0
```

The `Answer == "Yes"` converts to a boolean (TRUE/FALSE) which is mathematically handled as 1/0 in R (ie `mean(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE))` is the same as `mean(c(1, 0, 0, 0))` and both return 0.25.

To add a bar plot, just add `ggplot() + geom_col(aes(Participant, proportion))` to the command:

```
df %>%
  summarize(proportion = mean(Answer == "Yes"), 
            .by = "Participant") %>%
  ggplot() + geom_col(aes(Participant, proportion))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to plot the data plus proportions

```
df %>% 
  count(Answer, Participant) %>% 
  mutate(Prop = n/sum(n), .by = Participant) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_col(aes(Participant, Prop, fill=Answer))
```

[image: barplot]

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Participant = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", 
"P2", "P2", "P3"), Answer = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "No", "No")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

A way in *base* using `table`, `proportions`, `sort` and `barplot` using data from @Andre Wildberg (thanks!).

```
proportions(table(df), 1)[,"Yes"] |>
  sort(TRUE) |>
  barplot()
```

Alternative using `tapply`:

```
tapply(df$Answer=="Yes", df$Participant, mean) |>
  sort(TRUE) |>
  barplot()
```

[image: Barplot of proportions]